# Gambler's ruin stopping time

Tags: probability, markov-chains

I'm trying to show that the expected stopping time of the Gambler's Ruin game is $x(n-x)$, where the gambler starts with \$$x$ and the game stops at \$0 or \$$n$. The probabilities of gaining and losing \$1 at each time step are equal (1/2).

I've set up a recursion $\mathbb{E}(T_k) = \frac12 \mathbb{E}(T_{k-1}) + \frac12 \mathbb{E}(T_{k+1}) + 1$ where $T_k$ is the stopping time when the gambler has \$$k$. The recursion has base cases $\mathbb{E}(T_0) = \mathbb{E}(T_n) = 0$.

I'm not exactly sure how to proceed from here. I tried expanding the recursion even more, but this just leads to a mess of terms, and I'm not seeing the pattern. Any help would be very much appreciated!

Comment: The answer $x(n-x)$ was given as guidance for a proof using first-step analysis; I'm not allowed to use induction.

Comment: Rewrite as $E(T_k)-E(T_{k-1})=E(T_{k+1})-E(T_k)+2$ to see that the difference is linear hence $E(T_k)$ is quadratic with leading coefficient $-1$. Boundary conditions imply that it's $x(n-x)$.

Comment: @A.S. this makes sense intuitively -- but could you perhaps point me to a resource showing how to formally solve these types of equations?

Comment: These are called "linear difference equations" (in this case of order $2$). Here is the first [reference](https://www.cl.cam.ac.uk/teaching/2003/Probability/prob07.pdf) I found which specifically addresses this equation. I, however, like to think of these in terms of difference operator $\Delta$ so that your equation becomes $\Delta^2T=-\frac 1 2$ so you just need to "integrate"/sum twice to get a quadratic $E(T_n)$

Answer (score 3):

Let $u_k = \mathbb{E}\left[T_{k+1}\right] - \mathbb{E}\left[T_{k}\right]$, we have $u_k = u_{k-1} - 2$. The sequence $\left(u_k\right)_{k\in\mathbb{N}}$ is arithmetic : $$
u_k = -2k + u_0.
$$

But $u_0 = \mathbb{E}\left[T_{1}\right]$, $u_{n-1} = - \mathbb{E}\left[T_{n-1}\right] = -2(n-1) + \mathbb{E}\left[T_{1}\right]$ and $\mathbb{E}\left[T_{n-1}\right] = \mathbb{E}\left[T_{1}\right]$. So we get 
$$
u_0 = \mathbb{E}\left[T_{1}\right] = n-1
$$
and finally,
$$
\mathbb{E}\left[T_{k+1}\right] = n-1 - 2k + \mathbb{E}\left[T_{k}\right].
$$
Now,
\begin{align*}
\mathbb{E}\left[T_{x}\right] & = (n-1)x - 2\sum_{k=0}^{x-1}k \\
& = (n-1)x - x(x-1) \\
& = nx - x - x^2 + x \\
& = nx - x^2 \\
& = (n - x)x.
\end{align*}

Comment: Could you please explain why E[Tn-1]=E[T1] in detail? Although I do agree it is true  intuitively.

Comment: The time it takes for the game to end when you start from place $1$, on average, is the same as the time it takes when you start from place $n-1$

Comment: How did the first statement of $\mu_k = \mu_{k-1} -2$ hold? I am really struggling with this.

Comment: It comes from the way the recursion is set up, back in the question