# The Expected Number of Tosses in a Fair Coin Game until Heads Lead by $a$ or Tails Lead by $b$

Tags: probability, stochastic-processes

Given a fair coin, what is the expected number of coin tosses needed until either the number of heads exceeds the number of tails by $a$ or the number of tails exceeds the number of heads by $b$?

A direct approach to solving this problem involves establishing a series of linear equations:

Let $x_i$ represent the expected number of coin tosses when there are $i$ more heads than tails. Then, we can model the recursive relationship as:

$$
x_i = 1 + \frac{1}{2} x_{i + 1} + \frac{1}{2} x_{i-1}
$$

for $-b + 1 \leq i \leq a - 1$. Additionally, the boundary conditions are given by:

$$
x_{-b} = x_{a} = 0
$$

Using the above, we end up with a system of linear equations with $a + b + 1$ unknowns. Although solving this system directly gives the answer, it might require inverting a large matrix (we can solve it numerically by some software, see following PS). Is there a more straightforward method to obtain an analytical solution? Is there a general analytic formula for a biased coin with head $p$, tail $1-p$?

**PS**

Mathematica Code:

```
ExpectedTosses[p_, a_, b_] := 
 Module[{equations, boundaryConditions, solution},
  equations = 
   Table[X[i] == 1 + p (X[i + 1]) + (1 - p) (X[i - 1]), {i, -b + 1, 
     a - 1}];
  boundaryConditions = {X[a] == 0, X[-b] == 0};
  solution = 
   Solve[Join[equations, boundaryConditions], Table[X[i], {i, -b, a}]];
  Print[solution];
  X[0] /. solution[[1]]]

ExpectedTosses[1/2, 30, 20]
```

I've conducted several experiments with $p=\frac{1}{2}$ and observed that the expected value consistently turns out to be a whole integer. This leads me to believe there might be a straightforward formula underlying this phenomenon. For instance, upon observation, when
$a=b=n$, the expected value consistently emerges as $n^2$.

Comment: I think this problem is commonly known as the gambler's ruin. https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1533005/gamblers-ruin-stopping-time seems to give a solution to your particular question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For a fair coin, the easiest way to do it is with martingales.  Let $S_n$ be the number of heads minus the number of tails after $n$ tosses, so $S_0 = 0$ and $\mathbb{P}(S_{n+1} = S_n + 1) = \mathbb{P}(S_{n+1} = S_n - 1) = \frac 12$.  Note that $(S_n)$ is a martingale.  In particular,
\begin{align}\mathbb{E}[S_n] = S_0 = 0 \tag{1} \end{align} for all $n$.

Let $T_{a,b} = \min\{n : S_n = a \text{ or } S_n = -b\}$, which is what you want to find the expected value of.  We know $T_{a,b}$ is a stopping time, so $S^{T_{a,b}}_n := S_{n \wedge T_{a,b}}$ is also a martingale.  Because $|S^{T_{a,b}}_n|$ is bounded, we can replace $n$ in $(1)$ with $T_{a,b}$ to conclude
\begin{align*}
0 &= \mathbb{E}[S_{T_{a,b}}] = a \mathbb{P}(S_{T_{a,b}} = a) - b \mathbb{P}(S_{T_{a,b}} = b) = a \mathbb{P}(S_{T_{a,b}} = a) - b(1- \mathbb{P}(S_{T_{a,b}} = a)), 
\end{align*}
which implies
\begin{align*}
\mathbb{P}(S_{T_{a,b}} = a) = \frac{b}{a+b}.
\end{align*}

Now, note that the process $X_n := S_n^2 - n$ is also a martingale, so $\mathbb{E}[X_n] = X_0 = 0$.  In particular, this implies $\mathbb{E}[n] = \mathbb{E}[S_n^2]$ for all $n$.  Following similar reasoning as above, we can replace $n$ with $T_{a,b}$ in this equation to conclude
\begin{align*}
\mathbb{E}[T_{a,b}] &= \mathbb{E}[S_{T_{a,b}}^2] \\
&= a^2 \mathbb{P}(S_{T_{a,b}} = a) + b^2 \mathbb{P}(S_{T_{a,b}} = b) \\
&= \frac{a^2b + b^2 a}{a+b} \\
&= ab.
\end{align*}

When $a=b=n$, this gives $\mathbb{E}[T_{a,b}] = n^2$, as you observed from your code.